# Getting error trying to build ios flutter solution: Requested but did not find extension point with identifier

Tags: ios, flutter

I've tried all sorts of XCode reinstall of command line tools.  no changes.  Solution has nothing to do with WatchOS

`flutter build ios --debug`

Error

```
↳
2022-08-05 15:47:04.480 xcodebuild[67049:4259164] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of
plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-08-05 15:47:04.481 xcodebuild[67049:4259164] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier
Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
** BUILD FAILED **
```

Flutter Doctor shows no issues.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/shanejordan/Documents/flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f1875d570e (3 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
    • Engine revision e85ea0e79c
    • Dart version 2.17.6
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/shanejordan/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.46.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.134

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Podfile I'm using

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end


# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6339
# Should be referenced for anything below that transitively uses GoogleUtilities
def google_utilites
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/Environment'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/ISASwizzler'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/Logger'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/Network'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/Reachability'
  pod 'GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults'
end


require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  google_utilites

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: Please include your podfile here

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

1. Uncomment the platform in podfile

```dart
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'
```

2. Delete Pods folder, .symlinks folder
3. Run pod install in ios directory
4. Open runner. Xcworkspace file in xcode
5. Click on product and select clean build folder
6. If you are any warnings to upgrade dependencies please upgrade
7. Run the project from xcode once and all subsequent builds should work from your ide

Comment: i'll try working through these steps and see if I have a better result.  thanks!